# Zygote.Hessian: Mutating arrays is not supported

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I'm trying to calculate the laplacian of neural network. This is my code:

```
using Flux
using Zygote

model = Chain(Dense(2,5,sigmoid), Dense(5,1))

function laplace(x)
    a, b = size(x)
    Δ = Zygote.Buffer(zeros(b))
    deriv2 = sum(Diagonal(ones(a*b)).*Zygote.hessian(v -> sum(model(v)), x), dims=1)
    for i=1:b
        for j=1:a
            Δ[i] += deriv2[(i-1)*a+j]
        end
    end
    return copy(Δ)
end

gradient(x -> sum(laplace(x)), rand(2,5))
```

I'll see the same error even if I define a function like this:

```
function function(x)
    return sum(Zygote.hessian(v -> sum(model(v)), x))
end

gradient(x -> function(x), rand(2,5))
```

Why do I get this error?